# Docker network error connecting containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am having trouble wrapping my head around how to configure what I consider to be a pretty basic network setup in Docker.

Containers:

- Wordpress
- MariaDB
- Node.js

I've got the Wordpress & MariaDB containers up and running and chatting with eachother, but for some reason my Node.js container is unable to perform a basic HTTP call out to the Wordpress server. I immediately receive an `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.128.4:3000` error from my Node script.

I am running Docker Desktop Community on Mac OS v2.3.0.3.

My `docker-compose.yml` file looks like this:

```
services:

  db:
    image: mariadb:10.5.4-focal
    container_name: db
    volumes:
      - ./cms/conf/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./cms/sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=******
      - MYSQL_USER=******
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=******
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
    restart: always

  cms.mysite.local:
    container_name: cms.mysite.local
    build:
      context: ./cms
    image: mysite/cms:5.4.2
    ports:
      - '3000:80'
    volumes:
      - ./cms/conf/php/uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
      - ./cms/conf/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./cms/logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx
      - ./cms/app/public:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress
      - WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX=wp_
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=root
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=password
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always

  node:
    container_name: node
    build:
      context: ./www
    image: mysite/gatsby:2.23.12
    user: 'node'
    working_dir: /home/node/www
    volumes:
      - ./www:/home/node/www
      - /home/node/www/node_modules
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    depends_on:
      - cms.mysite.local
    restart: "always"
```

The `cms.mysite.local` container has an open port specified at `3000`. I modified my local Mac OS machine's `/etc/hosts` file to add a `127.0.0.1 cms.mysite.local` entry, and I am able to hit the Wordpress site in my browser and get a valid response. So it looks like everything is working there.

Then I have the following script set up in the `node` container:

```
const axios = require('axios')
const url = 'http://cms.mysite.local:80'
console.log('URL=' + url)
axios.get(url).then( (response) => {
  console.log('response=' + JSON.stringify(response.data))
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log('error=' + error)
})
```

I have this script set up to execute when the container starts. Everytime it runs, I get the error: `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.128.4:3000`. Sure enough, when I try to access `192.168.128.4:3000` manually in my MacOS browser, I do indeed get no connection.

Why is the Node.js script trying to access `http://192.168.128.4:3000` instead of my written `http://cms.mysite.local:3000/` URL?

How can I force it to use the URL that maps correctly to the Wordpress docker container? Or how can I set up my URL so that my `node` container can make HTTP calls to my `cms.mysite.local` container?

[Edit #1] I have also tried updating my Node.js script to call out to `http://cms.mysite.local:80/`. I added some logging to make the output a little more clear.

```
> node ./test.js
URL=http://cms.mysite.local:80
error=Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.128.4:80
```

[Edit 2: Urg. I did not appropriately stop & rebuild my docker image for edit. I do see the appropriate ports being used after restarting. #1]

[Solve: Thanks to Fernando and Shizzen83 for the port callout!]
Here's what was happening. I had my Wordpress site configured for port 3000 so that I could access it on that port through the browser. But I had a nginx config serving the site on port 80 inside of Docker. So Wordpress was issuing 301 redirects on port 80 requests to port 3000 because the internal Docker port didn't match the external Wordpress port. I switched out nginx to listen on port 3000 directly, and updated my docker-compose file to map `3000:3000` instead of `3000:80`. And now things all line up. Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be the port of `cms.mysite.local` you are exposing

```
ports:
  - 3000:80
```

which means that this container is mapped to port `3000` to outside (your host) but inside the docker network the container still have the `80` for incoming connections.

For your `node` container must be something like

```
axios.get('http://cms.mysite.local:80').then( (response) => {
  console.log('response=' + response.data)
})
.catch(function (error) {
 // handle error
console.log('error=' + error);
})
```

And `node` shows you the IP beacause he is resolving the DNS of your wordpress container inside the docker network

Comment: Thanks! I had already tried swapping out the ports to 80. Sorry I didn't make that clear in the original question; I've updated it to include this information.

Comment: Thanks Fernando! This was absolutely right. The core issue was that my Wordpress site had the Site URL set to port 3000, but my nginx running port 80. And Docker was handling the mapping of 3000:80.

Fixed this by having my nginx use port 3000 as well, and having Docker just map 3000:3000.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake comes from the port used by Node to reach Wordpress. When you set `3000:80` in `ports` section of a container, it means nothing more than a query sent onto host on port 3000 will be redirected to internal port 80 of Wordpress container. Though your Node container is not the host, so you have to directly reach port 80 instead.

Comment: Thanks! I had already tried swapping out the ports to 80. Sorry I didn't make that clear in the original question; I've updated it to include this information.